# Type func with interface parameter incompatible error

Tags: go

I have declared a new type `func` that takes any value that conforms to `interface{}`. However, when I invoke a function that has been passed as an argument (conforming to that type specification) I get an error.

Can somebody explain why this is the case? Below is the simplest example I could recreate the issue with.

```golang
type myfunc func(x interface{})

func a(num int) {
    return
}

func b(f myfunc) {
    f(2)
    return
}

func main() {
    b(a) // error: cannot use a (type func(int)) as type myfunc in argument to b
    return
}
```

Comment: `a` can take only ints, `b` needs a func that can take anything. If you pass `a` to `b` but `b` passes "astring" to its `f` argument, which is `a` in this case, instead of passing it `2` that would be an error, right? So the compiler stops you from doing that.

Comment: @mkopriva so you're saying that because `b` could theoretically pass anything to its argument `f`, the compiler generates an error?

Comment: As @mkopriva already explained, the following 2 are not compatible:  

func(int) AND func(interface{}).
In your case b, expects the 2nd kind but you are passing the 1st kind.

Comment: The compiler generates an error because the two types, `func(int)` and `func(interface{})`, are not the same and neither are they compatible. The benefit of that error is that you cannot write a program where you pass a string to a function that expects an int.

Comment: The first thing to understand is this: `interface{}` does **not** mean "any type". Really not. `interface{}` is a certain static type like uint16 and means "the empty interface". While you can assign everything to a variable of type "the empty interface" the empty interface is different from uint16, int, whatever other type. And function signatures must match one one one on each static type.

Comment: Right, ok. I think I understand now. Thanks all for the explanations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The concept you're looking for here is [*variance* in the type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)). Some type systems and types support *covariance* and *contravariance*, but Go's interfaces do not.

While an `int` can be passed to a function that expects `interface{}`, the same cannot be said about `func(int)` and `func(interface{})`, because interfaces do not behave covariantly.

If type `x` implements interface `ii`, it doesn't mean that `func(x)` implements `func(ii)`.

What you could do is pass `func(int)` into a function that expects `interface{}`, so you could do

```
package main

import "fmt"

func foo(x interface{}) {
    fmt.Println("foo", x)
}

func add2(n int) int {
    return n + 2
}

func main() {
    foo(add2)
}
```

Because `func(int)int` *does* implement `interface{}`.

---

In addition to the Wikipedia link at the top of the answer, [this post](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2018/covariance-and-contravariance-in-subtyping/) provides more details about the different kinds of variance programming languages support. It mostly uses other languages, because variance is best demonstrated with languages that support inheritance.